# What should I do after a question had a surprise answer?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, scope

I'm a little new. I had a problem on my VPS with infinite redirects and https. I asked about apache configs, but the answer turned out to be a WordPress plugin. So, what should I do?

I don't want to post it on the WordPress site because the problem began as a web server error and had nothing to do with writing WP code.

Should I move the question to Server Fault — or Webmasters? Which forum to ask on is a whole topic by itself.

Also, is it okay to change the title of my question to explain that it had a seemingly off-topic answer?

Should I do both, to ask and answer my question at the same time, phrasing the title as a tip, not a "question", on SF or WM?

Comment: WordPress is not off-topic on SO, so there's nothing you need to do. Questions are only closed or migrated if they're on the *wrong* site, and often there's more than one right site.